# How check automatically if there is an update on a package in my local nuget server with the same version

Tags: c#, git, build, nuget, git-tfs

In my company we work on the same app from different teams.

**Background**

- I have created a local nuget server
- Each team build it's own package
- After pushing to Git-TFS server, something **must** increase the version number from `x.y.z` to `x.y.z+1` inside `project-name`.nuspec`file and also inside each project's`packages.config` file using this package.
- New release will be created ater pushing to Git-TFS server so multiple releases will be created each day.
- Each team must work on the other team's latest version released packages

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to increase the version number in `project-name`.nuspec`file and also in each project's`packages.config` file using this package after pushing to Git-TFS? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?
2. How do I make each project check for update in a **specific packages** update in the build process?

Comment: How many teams and packages for each team are you dealing with?

Comment: For now we are 2 teams and each team can work on at list 2 solutions.

Comment: Is there business reasons why you can't combine the projects from the two solutions into one solution?

Comment: yes there is...

Comment: Have you tried to do this hot by push in Git-TFS server, but by build in your CI, of course, if you have it? Do you need to increase version number directly in the source files, not in the build artifacts?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria We currently don't have CI but the increasing should be as you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is a little dated, but here's an implementation of auto incrementing http://digitaldrummerj.me/Nuget-Auto-Incrementing-Version/

2) Getting the packages to auto-update for you would be a bit trickier, at that point, I would argue that the teams should have some level of communication that they released a new package and what changed

Comment: Every push to the git-tfs server, new release should be created so multiple releases will be created each day. There must be a sulotion. It can't be I'm the only developer in the world in this situation.

Comment: What does your branching strategy look like?

Comment: Each developer upload from his personal task branch to development branch and when his pull request is accepted, new release needs to be created with increasing number.